# Genetic algorithm, how to define a fitness function for generated source code

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I'm working in a simple genetic algorithm that generates Java source code but I'm having problems to define a good fitness function, right now I'm using a simple Java compiler to run the code (an individual is a simple string that contains a portion of a Java code), then getting the number of errors, the less errors, the higher the fitness, but this is not giving me good results so far, it reaches to a point where all members of the population have the same fitness and never gets higher.

Individuals are generated using a combination of Java keywords and some method and class names, so it generates strings like this:

- int method,=float......
- void,int,,;......
- method(,;;=.....

Is it possible to know than a generated code is better than the other? maybe a combination of number of errors with something else.

Comment: I think the (one of very many?) problem here is that one error might "hide" many other errors further "downstream", so if you fix that error, the fitness would seem to get lower.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use different approach and very different fitness function. Altering the one you have will be hard to improve things. I tried using genetic alforithms on some math equations and they stopped improving things before i
I was getting satisfying results. I spent a lot of time adding and removing minor things from the fitness function and no luck.

For example you can consider using some code metrics (unwanted operations etc, dummy read/writes to variables or registers etc). You may want to write your own VM for that that will give you results.

Alternatively use very different approach (not GA but finding the right path if you know heuristics or use genetic programming where you alter branches of tree containing instructions of your code). From what you are saying you will need to make a more significant changes.

Good luck. Please let update us. Very interested in knowing what worked the best.